# Can you change MongoDB Charts Geospacial Map?

Tags: c#, mongodb, leaflet, dashboard, mongodb-charts

I am using MongoDB Charts to attempt to implement a Dashboard.
The GeoSpacial Charts use appear to use Leaflet and a very simple map.

See Here:
[image]

Is is possible to use a more detailed map at closer ranges. For Example Open Street Maps?
Which is also used by leaflet?

For reference I have found nothing online indicating that it is or isn't possible.

I am currently using a Blazor web app and Syncfusion for this dashboard, if that helps. I know there is a possibility to embed the map within an IFrame which I have done. There is also an embedded sdk.

Thanks for your time,
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer here](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/changing-the-geospacial-map-is-it-possible/200030/2), MongoDB Charts doesn't let you configure or change the map. It does suggest you can use `.getData()` and use your own mapping component.

Comment: Thanks for the response, the question you linked was actually my question on their forums! I guess its just a very niche question :D

Comment: Well, seems like you got the official answer then. I'd say it makes my answer the right one. You could also answer yourself here copying the answer you got.